# Multiple attribute values jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I'm selecting DOM elements with the same attribute, but two different values using jQuery:

```
$( 'input[the-attribute="value1"], input[the-attribute="value2"]' )
```

Is there a more efficient or compact way to do this?

Please, bear in mind that there are many possible values, but I'm just searching for two specific values in this case.

Thanks :)

Comment: Assign the same class to both of them?

Comment: Do the attribute values start with the same string? In the above example you could do: $('input[the-attribute^="value"]) — https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the attribute, like this

```
$( 'input[the-attribute]' )
```

*Note, if the values you test on does not start with the same characters, like in sample 3, then they need to be added as a list, exactly how you do already, or as suggested/commented, add a specific class to the one's to target*

Read more here about attribute selectors: [MDN Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

---

Sample 1, target elements having the attribute `[the-attribute]`

```js
$( 'div[data-color]' ).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hey 1</div>
<div data-color="green">Hey 2</div>
<div data-color="blue">Hey 3</div>
<div>Hey 4</div>
```

Sample 2, target elements having 2 (or more) attribute `[the-attribute][the-attribute2]`

```js
$( 'div[data-color][data-image]' ).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hey 1</div>
<div data-color="green">Hey 2</div>
<div data-color="blue" data-image="icon">Hey 3</div>
<div>Hey 4</div>
```

Sample 3, target elements where the attribute's value *starts with width* `[data-size^=width]`

```js
$( 'div[data-size^=width]' ).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hey 1</div>
<div data-size="width200">Hey 2</div>
<div data-size="width400">Hey 3</div>
<div>Hey 4</div>
```

Sample 4, target elements where the attribute's value *contains the value* `[data-size*=width]`

```js
$( 'div[data-size*=width]' ).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hey 1</div>
<div data-size="height100width200">Hey 2</div>
<div data-size="length300width400">Hey 3</div>
<div>Hey 4</div>
```

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but I'll say that this is not a good solution in my case as there are a lot more elements with the same attribute. Here I'm just searching for two specific values, but there are a lot more values. Thanks anyway. :) Adding that extra info the question.

Comment: @timo can you update your question then with the actual values you are trying to select by.

Comment: @JackZelig a real example is 'input[data-col="height"], input[data-col="width"]' but I guess the example in the question is juts fine to get the idea.

Comment: Ok man, then as far as I know either select using the "data-col" attribute as suggested, or do it as you are in your question. There is no shorter way AFAIK.

Comment: @JackZelig Updated answer

Comment: @timo Updated answer

Comment: Thanks everybody!

Comment: @timo I added/updated the 2:nd, to show you, you can use more than one attributes (each can be with or without values)